# how to find libraries for xcode iphone developing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

i am watching my first xcode tutorial on youtube , it says that i have to make new "based view application" but i found "simple view application" i thing it is the same , am i right? then on the tutorial there are somethings like buttons , textareas... to put it in the view but i can't find it with my xcode 4.5.2 , i read on google it is from tool then library but i don't have "tool", what should i do to see it please? by the way i just have mac os x lion 10.7.4 and xcode 4.5.2 maybe i have to install another programs ?
this is what i see[image]

and when i press new project check what i see, there is no "view based application"[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right, you have three buttons above "View", click the right one to open the right sidebar. In the bottom right corner, you find your UI Objects. Nothing else needed.

Click the small "box" (3rd of the four symbols) in the bottom right.

Comment: i press that but didn't got anything , please see the question i added a photo of what i see

Comment: you the one man, i really thank you, i will accept your answer

Comment: please would you check the question i added a photo of what types of projects i can see in my xcode , why can't i see "view based application" ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which tutorial you are watching but if its unclear you can allways follow this tutorial. If you scroll down you will find what you are looking for! Good luck

[Create View Based Application from scratch](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-view-based-application-from-scratch/)

[Another example of same thing](http://www.nearsoft.com/blog/creating-a-view-based-iphone-application.html)

[image]

Comment: i am watching "bucky" tutorials from "thenewboston" , i will check the link , i don't have view based app , i have simple view app , is it the same ?

Comment: When you are about to create a new project for iOS device you have 7 different types of application types. View-based app is one of them. Take a look at the links i gave you.

Comment: i don't have a type called "based view app" please check the edit i added a photo

Comment: Sorry dude I created a screenshot on how to get UI objects, came too late .

Comment: i really thank you for help but i accept his answer because he told me before , i hope i could accept two answers :( , but why your screen is clear and my clear is full and how you make the screen contains just the view